# rails console not working 'bundle exec rails c' on kubernetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I am trying to run rails console using `bundle exec rails c` command. But console is not opening. I have not installed ruby or rails using apt, instead using rvm and gems respectively.
But when i `ctr + c` to terminate command i get some error as below

> /mypath/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in
>   connect: Interrupt

I am not able to understand exact error.

Comment: Check if you can manually (i.e. by `mysql` connect to your DB server, as it seems to be connectivity problem).

Comment: Yes, issue is solved. In aws there were insufficient permissions for db